# Passing a function as a parameter within a class

Tags: c++, arduino, refactoring, esp8266

So I'm trying to enlist the use of [ESPAsyncWebServer](https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer#respond-with-content-coming-from-a-file-containing-templates) for a project, and due to the size of said project I'm refactoring my code into a bunch of different libraries. This is to be part of the Client Server handling section.

I've determined how to effectively pass the *request to separate functions for the purpose of cleaning my code up. I.E.
Within my Libraries .cpp file

```
server->on("/heap", HTTP_GET, [this](AsyncWebServerRequest *request) { handleHeap(request); });
```

which fires:

```
void CServer::handleHeap(AsyncWebServerRequest *request) { request->send(200, "text/plain", String(ESP.getFreeHeap())); }
```

Where I'm running into an issue is trying to pass in my "Processor" function to the response for templating.

```
String CServer::processor(const String &var)
{
if (var == "locationLat")
return String(gps.location.lat());
return String();
}

void CServer::handleGPS(AsyncWebServerRequest *request)
{
request->send(SPIFFS, "/gps.htm", String(), processor);
}
```

> error: no matching function for call to
>   'AsyncWebServerRequest::send(fs::FS&, const char [9], String, )

Trying to pass processor() in a Lambda also doesn't compile, because there isn't a parameter going in.

> error: no matching function for call
>   to '`CServer::processor()`' `request->send(SPIFFS, "/gps.htm", String(), [this] { processor(); });`
>   ^ lib\CServer\CServer.cpp:128:66: note:
>   candidate is: lib\CServer\CServer.cpp:108:8: note: String
>   `CServer::processor(const String&)`

sooo, how do I handle passing the required processor function, into my response parameters as instructed in the guide [here](https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer#respond-with-content-coming-from-a-file-containing-templates)?

For reference:

```
String processor(const String& var)
{
if(var == "HELLO_FROM_TEMPLATE")
return F("Hello world!");
return String();
}

// ...

//Send index.htm with template processor function
request->send(SPIFFS, "/index.htm", String(), false, processor);
```

Fine if its all in main.cpp, but that is not what I want to do!

Comment: I assume it works fine in `main` because it's a local function, whereas your `processor` function is a member function. I don't know for certain, but could you just wrap the parameter in a lambda?

Comment: Presumably you could add a string argument to your lambda and pass that to process?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since your processor function is a class method, you'll need to bind it with the implicit `this` argument.

We can find the callback typedef : `typedef std::function<String(const String&)> AwsTemplateProcessor;`

```
request->send(SPIFFS, "/index.htm", String(), false, [this](const String &var) -> String { return this->processor(var); });
```

The lambda here is taking a `const String &var` as parameter such as the `AwsTemplateProcessor`, and we precise the return type of the `AwsTemplateProcessor` function by writing `-> String` after the lambda prototype. By precising the parameters **and** the return type correctly the send method can relate the lambda to the `std::function` (`AwsTemplateProcessor`).

Comment: With the first method I'm getting the compilation error: 'placeholders' is not a namespace-name. The lambda works! It looks like the "-> String" portion made all the difference. Could you shed some light on what this portion of the lambda is doing? If you compare it to what @Jarod42 posted below (which the AWS function doesn't match)that appears to be the only difference.

Comment: While it is compiling, I'm getting the following warning: lib\CServer\CServer.cpp:128:108: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
   request->send(SPIFFS, "/gps.htm", String(), false, [this](const String &var) -> String { processor(var); }); and the template processor is not functioning, so I'm wondering if the return is getting lost somewhere?

Comment: You need to return the processor in order to return the `String` in the lambda. `[this](const String &var) -> String { return processor(var); }`

Comment: This was the issue and makes sense. Functioning as expected now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Make your method `static`, or call should be:

```
void CServer::handleGPS(AsyncWebServerRequest *request)
{
    request->send(SPIFFS, "/gps.htm", String(), [this](const String& var) { return processor(var); });
}
```