# Passing processor-function in library for ESP AsyncWebServerRequest

Tags: c++11, asynchronous, webserver, esp32, arduino-esp32

I'm trying to include the ESPAsyncWebServer lib in an own C++ class/library. I'm struggling to pass the processor function when starting a server.

Same problem was discussed here:
[Calling member function by pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71305951/calling-member-function-by-pointer)
[Passing a function as a parameter within a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59575326/passing-a-function-as-a-parameter-within-a-class?newreg=ec847a5a7794414fbbda00be2ec41ad4)
...but I can't find the solution.

My code looks like this:

code.ino:

```
#include "SoftwareUpdater.h"

AsyncWebServer server(80);
SoftwareUpdater Updater(&server);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Updater.initialise();
}

void loop() {
}
```

Softwareupdater.cpp:

```
#include "SoftwareUpdater.h"

SoftwareUpdater::SoftwareUpdater(AsyncWebServer *_server) {
  server = _server;
}

void SoftwareUpdater::initialise() {
  server->on("/manager", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
    request->send(SPIFFS, "/index.htm", String(), false, [&](const String &var) -> String {
      return processor(var);
    });
  });
  server->begin();
};

String SoftwareUpdater::processor(const String &var) {
  if (var == "var_manager") {
    return "text";
  }
};
```

Softwareupdater.h:

```
#ifndef SoftwareUpdater_h
#define SoftwareUpdater_h

#include "FS.h"
#include "SPIFFS.h"
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>

class SoftwareUpdater {
private:
  void _setupAsyncServer();

public:
  AsyncWebServer *server;
  String processor(const String &var);

  SoftwareUpdater(AsyncWebServer *server);
  void initialise();
};

#endif
```

The error is:

> cannot call member function 'String SoftwareUpdater::processor(const
> String&)' without object exit status 1 Compilation error: 'this' was
> not captured for this lambda function

[Picture: This is the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBqJS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call the properties of an object in a lambda function, which does not know the object. So, you would have to pass the object, too.

```
server->on("/manager", HTTP_GET, [this](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
  request->send(SPIFFS, "/index.htm", String(), false, [this](const String &var) -> String {
    return this->processor(var);
  });
});
```

Comment: Perfect…that works. That was an really easy fix. Thanks!

Comment: Good! If it worked for you, please accept the answer!